# Facebook iframe share and invite buttons not working on IE

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

Using WooBox I created a custom tab for a Page. This custom tab uses a iFrame to display a PHP file on my server. Happens is that this PHP has a Facebook Share and a Facebook Invite button that WORK on Firefox but DON'T WORK on Internet Explorer:

The tab in question is this one: http://www.facebook.com/?ref=canvas#!/pages/Mulheres-Apaixonantes/127782210574538?sk=app_369079553142218

The PHP file is fairly simple, I'm posting here the relevant bits:

```
<?php header("p3p: CP=\"ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV HONK\"");?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

Then comes the HEAD tag with 2 meta tags, the title and the style tag and then:

```
<script>
function fb_share(){
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Jardim Botânico UTAD',
    caption: '',
    link: 'http://facebook.com/utadjb',
    picture: 'http://jb.utad.pt/img/site/logotipo200200.png',
    description: 'Acabei de ver a página do facebook do Jardim Botânico UTAD!'
},
function(response){
    if(response){
        alert('Post was published.');
    }else{
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
});
}

function fb_invite(){
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Acabei de ver a página do facebook do Jardim Botânico UTAD em http://facebook.com/utadjb! Vê também!'
},
function(response){
    if (response){
        alert('Post was published.');
    }else{
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Inside the  this is how the buttons are called:

```
      <div id="share_posttowall" class="shareoption"><span>Partilhe no seu mural</span><a onclick="fb_share(); return false;" class="fbbluebutton" href="#">Partilhar</a></div>
      <div id="share_sendinvite" class="shareoption"><span>Convide os seus amigos</span><a onclick="fb_invite(); return false;" class="fbbluebutton" href="#">Convidar</a></div>
```

Anybody knows why are these two buttons not working on Internet Explorer? I've already exhausted all possibilites of troubleshooting ...

Answer (score 1):

> I've already exhausted all possibilites of troubleshooting ...

Except for looking into your browser’s error console, you mean?

On clicking any of these buttons, I get something on the lines of “FB is not defined” in **all** browsers – and this is not particularly suprising, because you don’t seem to be embedding the JS SDK **at all.**

Comment: Didn't even know IE had a error console.Thanks so much for the help. :)